# create a PhoneCall record in Crm using Javascript

Tags: javascript, crm, phone-call

When I try to create a PhoneCall record in Crm using Javascript, I got following error message, I cannot figure out the reason, any help?

```
 {
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseText": "{\r\n\"error\": {\r\n\"code\": \"\", \"message\": {\r\n\"lang\": \"en-US\", \"value\": \"Error processing request stream. The property name 'from' specified for type 'Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.PhoneCall' is not valid.\"\r\n}\r\n}\r\n}",
    "status": 400,
    "statusText": "Bad Request"
} 
 "error" 
 "Bad Request" 

<code>

    var fromArray = [];
 var FromActivityParty = {
      PartyId:
     {
      Id: Xrm.Page.context.getUserId(),
      LogicalName: "systemuser"
     },
      ActivityId: {
       Id: TeamId,
       LogicalName: "team"
      },
      ParticipationTypeMask: { Value: 1 }
     };
 fromArray[0] = FromActivityParty;

 var toArray = [];
 var ToActivityParty = {
    PartyId:
     {
      Id: Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId(),
      LogicalName: "account"
     },
      ActivityId: {
       Id: TeamId,
       LogicalName: "team"
      },
      ParticipationTypeMask: { Value: 2 }
     }; 
  toArray[0] = ToActivityParty;

    var PhoneCall = {   
        from: fromArray, 
        to: toArray,
        Subject: "Create a phonecall record",
        OwnerId: fromArray,
        PhoneNumber: phoneNumber
    }


        CrmRestKit.Create("PhoneCall", PhoneCall)
                .fail(function (xhr, status, errorThrown) 
                { 
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr, null, 4)); 
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(status, null, 4)); 
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown, null, 4)); 

                })
                .done(function (data, status, xhr) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    }

</code>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the REST endpoint, you need to add the **To** and **From**  using the relationship with the **activity party** entity.

Here is the code I use:

```js
var phoneCall = {};

phoneCall.phonecall_activity_parties = [
 new ActivityParty(2, "systemuser", "GUID"),
 new ActivityParty(1, "contact", "GUID")
]; //2 = 'To'            1 = 'From'

//TODO: Call CREATE using phoneCall object.

function ActivityParty(typeMask, logicalName, partyId) {
 if (partyId && partyId[0] === '{') {
  partyId = partyId.substring(1, partyId.length - 1);
 }
 this.PartyId = {
  LogicalName : logicalName,
  Id : partyId
 };
 this.ParticipationTypeMask = {
  Value : typeMask
 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the error message sounds pretty clear to me.
"from" seems not to be a valid property name for the phone call type.

A quick guess: Have you tried to use "From" with an upper case? I see that your other properties are written this way.

Comment: Yes, I did try "From" then I will get  "Error processing request stream. The property name 'From' specified for type 'Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.PhoneCall' is not valid."